# How do i paint a panel with the obtained colour of pixel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm trying to get a pixel colour from the picturebox and painting the panel with the corresponding colour every time i click. How do i display the cursor coordinates on the form as well? Can you tell me what is wrong?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    Color colorpt;
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        int x = e.X;
        int y = e.Y;
        textBox1.Text = string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}", x, y);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            colorpt = img.GetPixel(x, y);
        }
        panel1.BackColor = colorpt;
        img.Dispose();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\1.png");
    }
}
```

}

This is my entire code that i am running.

This is the result:
[demo of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Fg1.gif)

Comment: You are never calling/triggering `panel1_Paint` after setting `colorpt = img.GetPixel(x, y);`. Why don't you just do `panel1.BackColor = img.GetPixel(x, y);` in your `MouseDown` event?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. How do i trigger panel1Paint? Sorry I'm new to c#

Comment: You also don't want to generate a new Bitmap just to get the color of one pixel. Use the existing (no need for  `Bitmap img = new Bitmap(Form1.pic);`)

Comment: Also, the MessageBox doesnt seem to be showing me the mouse coordinates

Comment: Jimi, i Intend to make more panels to get more colors. Could i spawn a new panel whenever i do a mouse click?

Comment: The mouse coordinates are relative to the PictureBox client rectangle, not your Image. I think I've already told you that you need to offset the mouse position considering the Image scale.

Comment: Why not just replace `colorpt = img.GetPixel(x, y);` with `panel1.BackColor = img.GetPixel(x, y);`  There's no "Paint" handler required.

Comment: What is currently **WITHIN** picturebox1?  Does it have an IMAGE assigned to it?...or just a SOLID COLOR assigned to the BackColor property?

Comment: It has an image WITHIN it.

Comment: If your PB has an image in it, then create the Bitmap using that image: `Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);`

Comment: _How do i trigger panel1Paint?_ `panel1.Invalidate();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, I can paint a panel with the obtained color of pixel.

I think there is no need to use Paint event and I suggest that you use textbox to show the

coordinate of the cursor.

You can refer to the following code.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    Color colorpt;
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        int x = e.X;
        int y = e.Y;
        textBox1.Text = string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}", x, y);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            colorpt = img.GetPixel(x, y);
        }
        panel1.BackColor = colorpt;
        img.Dispose();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\1.png");
    }
}
```

Pic:
[image]
Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but i was not able to replicate the result incorporated in my code, neither could i get the result by running your code directly. Could you please check?

Comment: The textbox and click event both fail to trigger for some reason.

Comment: @RD, I have checked it. There is no problem for me. You can create a new winform app to check it. Please remember click the left key of the cursor.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT okay let me try. Is there any dependence on the resolution of "D:\\1.png" i.e what i replace this with?

Comment: @RD, I think there is no related to the resolution of the picture. I used the picture so that I can check it easier. I have uploaded here, you can use it.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT I have edited my post and added the result i am getting with my own png. Note [SizeMode=Normal]

Comment: @RD, I am confused. Why the picture will occur 'g'? It is impossible for textbox.text to show this.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT Sorry, i just noticed! that was a freak keyboard button press

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT when i ran the same code in your project, it works. But if i run the same code from a new solution, it doesnt work. What is this problem pointing to?

Comment: It may be related to the specific picture. I suggest that you can find some pictures with clear colors so that it is easy for us to test.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT i used many images, loaded with your csproj file and it worked. I copied the SAME code to a new winform and it wouldnt duplicate the result!

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT .NET issue?

Comment: @RD, I am not sure if it is an issue. Because I can not reproduce your problem. Maybe you can ask new question in stack overflow.

Comment: @Jimi i was able to compensate for the pixel offset with this solution to my code : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60444151/13710873)